# 13: Permission denied php 5.6 fpm on ubuntu 14.06 with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am not able to run php fpm on nginx. I am getting permission error with www-data user/group. My error log is as below. I tried giving permission to the user www-data with different solutions over internet but didnt worked. I am running codeingiter framework. Please check error log below

> 10673#10673: *19456 stat() "/var/www/html/testphp/api/ajax/getdetails" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 11.11.1.11, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /api/ajax/getroomdetails/201 HTTP/1.1", h$
>
> 10673#10673: *19456 stat() "/var/www/html/testphp/api/ajax/getdetails" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 11.11.1.11, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /api/ajax/getroomdetails/201 HTTP/1.1", h$
>
> 10673#10673: *19456 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.11.1.11, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /api/ajax/getdetails HTTP/1.1$

Please suggest how can I give correct permissions to run php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your file permissions
cd /you Directory
then type
ls -l
after that you can use

chown -R root:www-data   /Directory
chmod g+w -R   /Directory

or

chmod +x  /Directory

Comment: maybe you can check https://websistent.com/fix-connect-to-php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream-nginx-error/